# Open ALPR-frequency based notifications

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, crm

I'm helping a client build a system for his high traffic car wash. The owner of the wash would like to upsell certain customers based on the frequency of their car washes. 
Example, if a car is getting a wash 2 times a month, the owner would like a notification when that car is about to get its 3rd was for the month and sell them a monthly car wash club membership to increase revenue.

I am using OpenALPR with my Axis 1427l camera and the OpenALPR axis agent installed on the axis camera. 
Currently we are using alerts to trigger when cars are detected at the wash, but OpenAlpr does not support time based or frequency base notifications natively in their web app. So I have to manually create an alert for each plate and then see the history to see if the selling opportunity for my client is there. It's time consuming and not automated.

My goal is trigger an alert when a license plate is detected for the second or third time in that 31 day (month) period.

Open Alpr supports custom webhooks as well.

Any ideas, thank you Frank.

Answer (score 0):

By no means am I an expert, but this is what I thought of:

For each plate detection, add it to a database along with the date and time.

Before or after that function (depending on your query) check the plate against the database (within the last 31 days) to see how many entries there are. If there are three entries, then send alert.

Sidenote:  Do those cameras work well?  Is it hard to get OpenALPR up and running?

Comment: That sounds like it can work. It's tough moving data from the Open Alpr program into custom environments though. The camera works well, i chose it because OpenAlpr provides an Axis agent that runs on the camera, so no command line neccessary for setup.

Comment: Re your sidenote, I've recently built an iOS app around OpenALPR. It was admittedly a pain in the ass to set up (iOS specific problems), however I now have it running smoothly in real time. Works very fast. Entire project only took 3 days.

Comment: @Cathal I am trying to build the OpenLPR sample code but the steps are difficult to follow. Do you have steps to make the sample code work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @PratikMistry Follow the steps here - https://github.com/twelve17/openalpr-ios . With some fidgeting around you should be able to get it to work. To make it work in real-time, you will need to manually draw images from camera over the screen.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. I figured it out by the way last night. Again thanks for reply @Cathal